# How do I switch string arguments on main

Tags: c, shell, arguments, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I have a c program which should take the first argument and check which function matches it.

Example:

```
./test.o blabla
```

Code:

```
main(int argc, const char* argv) {
    switch (argv[1]) {
        case "blabla":
            do_omething(argv[2]); break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void do_something(const char* param) {
    // ....
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `switch` on a C string, that's its *address,* not its contents.

You should use something like `strcmp` to check if the *content* matches:

```
if (strcmp (argv[1], "blabla") == 0)
    do_something(argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirement is but may be you can do something like below

```
switch(*argv[1){

 case 'b':
          if (strcmp (argv[1], "blabla") == 0)
              do_it_for_blabla();
          break;
 case 'c':
         if( compare with wait ever )
             do_what_ever();
         break;
 default:
         //do nothing and break;
         break;        

}
```